# situational count - python

Tags: python, count

I have a spreadsheet in excel, named as Students

`Year - City - Anniversary - Gender - Course Status - School Origin`

```
 2018 - SP - 13/05/1990 - M - Registered - Public
 2019 - RJ - 12/05/1990 - F - Registered - Particular
 2017 - SP - 13/05/1990 - M - Closed Enrollment - Public
```

I'm using google colab, I know how to count the values, but I don't know how to do a situational count, for example:

1. I would like to know how many male students have left the course.
2. Which city had more students who dropped out of the course.
3. By year, what was the number of students from public and private schools.

Where should I start and how should I code it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas counting and summing specific conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions)

Comment: No, because the values ​​I want to relate are in different columns, I don't know how to work that way.

Comment: did you read the second part where he used the & operator ?

Comment: Yes, but what would the contif code look like? I've never used it, it's giving error here

Comment: [counting-duplicate-values-in-pandas-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33993693/15649230) will also be useful for getting dropped students per city.

Comment: and i think the third one is just doing a filter on private or public school then a groupby year then count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df is your dataframe , just combining [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993592/counting-duplicate-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('sheet.xlsx')
```

1. 

```py
count_males_left = int(df[(df["Gender"]=="M") & (df["Course Status"]!="Registered")].count()[0])
```

2. 

```py
df_cities_count = df.groupby(['City']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

3. 

```py
df_public_by_year = df[df["School Origin"] == "Public"].groupby(['Year']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: In code 1, it is giving error "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>"

Comment: @Skye i editted the answer to solve that issue.